# Are these questions about balanced parentheses really duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

I had recently asked [a question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65526/bracket-balancing). It received 13 upvotes and 3 close votes as a duplicate of another question. It's not an exact duplicate, but both Qs are similar. That [other question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21562/fun-with-matching-braces) also has *exactly* 13 upvotes and 3 close votes as duplicate of my question! (Data as per 9:50 am 3 Dec GMT)

Apart from the fact that this is a really amazing coincidence, I would request a moderator to decide which Q is a duplicate (I don't mind if it is mine), or otherwise explain to the close-voters as to why both Qs should remain open.

P.S. I found 2 tags [duplicates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicates) and [exact-dupliactes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exact-dupliactes) while tagging this question. Aren't they duplicates of each other? ;)

Comment: Re: last paragraph, I merged [exact-duplicates] into [duplicates] (because the latter is golfier, of course).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think either one should be closed.

- The other one includes a ton of bonuses. While I don't think they are a great idea, they significantly change the challenge. Also, without the bonuses, the other challenge is only about handling a single type of bracket.
- Your challenge adds priorities to the bracket types. It's not only about correct balancing but also about the correct nesting hierarchy, which I think makes a significant difference.

I do think yours is the better question, but that doesn't make the other one a duplicate of yours.

Also, the three close votes on your question actually have a completely different dupe target. All three close votes are with respect to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11917/8478), which as I've said in a comment on your question I think is also completely different.